# Send only one input value with form submit in php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a condition where there are 5 different menu items and in a row and one form.

For each of the menu item there is a input value in the form, which looks like this:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <?php 
           foreach($menu_items as $item){?>
           <div id='' class=''>
               <?php echo ('menu item description here');?>
               <input type='text' name='something' value='something'>
           </div>
       <?php 
       } 
    ?>
   <button type='submit'>send</button>
</form>
```

Now i need only to send only one input value with form submit that has the menu class 'active'.

Is there a simple approach to this?

Comment: You need to process your value before submit using JQuery event handler `$("form").submit(function(event) { /* ... */ });`.

Comment: id's must be unique. Inserting a blank id for each item is essentially setting them all to the same id. you're not giving anything the 'active' class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give a shot

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes the ids are set unique, was just giving the overview of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to the event thrown by your form, and process your form before sending it.

You can follow this example to perform this task :

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent sending the form before we processed the form

        var active_input        =   $(".active")[0];        
        var active_input_value  =   active_input.val();

        $.ajax({
                url     :   "php_file_to_call.php"
            ,   method  :   "post"
            ,   data    :   { something : active_input_value }
        });
    });
});
```

The Ajax call (which could have been a `$.post()`) is necessary since you cannot submit the actual form because it does not prevent un-active element to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler way of doing it:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
   <select id="example" name="example">
     <option value="something">Option 1</option>
     <option value="something">Option 2</option>
     <option value="something">Option 3</option>
     <option value="something">Option 4</option>
     <option value="something">Option 5</option>
   </select>

   <button type='submit'>send</button>
</form>
```

now when you send the form using PHP it will only send the value of the selected option. `<select>` can be followed by as many `<option>` blocks as you want.

Comment: but i need the user to enter the input as text

Comment: You could create a single <input> where the user inputs the text and then selects for what option it is?